# How to share image to Snapchat from my android app?

Tags: android, android-sharing, snapchat

I'm adding share feature in my app, and everything works fine except sharing to Snapchat. When I send "SEND" intent Snapchat only opens it own camera preview and my picture is lost. I tried different things, but nothing helps. Also when I share via standard Android sharing screen, Snapchat successfully opens it. So here is my code:

```
 var tempFile = File(filePath)
        val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sharingIntent.type = "image/jpg"
        sharingIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        val image = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, tempFile)
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image)
        sharingIntent.`package` = "com.snapchat.android"
        return sharingIntent
```

I use FileProvider :

```
  <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_path"/>
    </provider>
```

And such paths:

```
<paths>
<cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
```

***Can you help me please to figure out what is the problem?
Thanks for all the answers!***

Answer (score 6):

Some app (like Snapchat) use unobvious  way of accepting sent Media, so you should set to your intent component:

```
intentComponent = ComponentName("com.snapchat.android", "com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity")
intent.component = intentComponent
//use component instead of setting package
```