# Sending Plain/Text Intent to SnapChat doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, snapchat

This is my code to send a simple text

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Download this App");
intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Via Snapchat"));
```

It works for all other messaging apps but it doesn't work for Snapchat. This code only opens the Snapchat app.

Comment: ignore that link text. I have updated my question @LarsH

Answer (score 1):

This is how to share a text from snapchat direct message.
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51361192/5939682 it is required to set the component instead of the package for sharing via snapchat. This is the working code for me.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT TO SEND");
            ComponentName intentComponent = new ComponentName("com.snapchat.android", "com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity");
            intent.setComponent(intentComponent);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapchat.android")));
            }
        }
```

If the app is not installed it throws the ActivityNotFoundException, so we handle that. 
You can show a message as "App is not installed" or direct the user to appstore.